# Error message when loading parquet file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def load_google(code):
    url = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={code}"
    file = requests.get(url)
    bytesio = BytesIO(file.content)
    return pd.read_parquet(bytesio, dtype_backend="pyarrow")

def load_data():
    list_fonds = load_google('161Bg01QO6sqBzgQbeuDrvhApPSxQqOGz')
    list_sdg   = load_google('163OEuakI8pEVx2t3Myy7KrGlM3YgD5zr')
    list_aum = load_google('1679R9CLRCvtzlDutH98BJ03eLWq2O2Av')
    categorie_fonds = load_google('16XGciQdAasNLVNPA-FRChInhOkyEN20O')
    iso_pays = load_google('166Kcz-KS2p8ypbilSOdshAx-nlSbkAll')
    return list_sdg, list_fonds, list_aum, iso_pays, categorie_fonds

# import of data 
list_sdg, list_fonds, list_aum, iso_pays, categorie_fonds = load_data()
```

I am trying to get parquet file from google drive file. I get the code of my file but sometimes it works and sometimes it does not and then I get this error message:

`ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '<Buffer>': Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.`

Why ? any help will be helpful

Comment: What version of pandas are you using, your example run perfectly fine on latest pandas. Also the error seems to be related to a content that is not a complete parquet file. Maybe the error was transient and now the problem is solved.

Comment: i am using pandas 2.1.1. The problem is that sometimes it works fine and sometimes not and I get the error message that I mentioned

Comment: It may happens while the file is being updated, hence incomplete and missing the magic bytes in the footer. Probably nothing wrong with your code, but you need to handle the case when file is not complete.

Comment: " but you need to handle the case when file is not complete" : what do you mean ?